# Open different Activities on pathPrefixes /abc and /abc/def

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have two urls. For example:

1. `http://host.com/abc/12345`
2. `http://host.com/abc/def/12345`

Where an `12345` - is some id.

I want to open different activities for these urls.

Currently I have next implementation in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.Activity1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" android:pathPrefix="/abc"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.Activity2"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" android:pathPrefix="/abc/def"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

First url works great: when I tap on it android suggest me to use *some other apps* or my **Activity1**.

But problem appears when I tap on second url: android suggest me to use *some other apps* or my **Activity1** or my **Activity2**.

So my question is: is there a way to exclude **Activity1** from list of suggestions.

I tried to play with `pathPattern` and tried to googling how to exclude url from **IntentFilter** but I failed.

Comment: try changing your pathPrefix from /abc to something else in Activity2

Comment: Hi @AshishShukla Could you suggest me on what I can change it? Because url I can not change.

Comment: you can post your answer ,it will be appreciated and might be helpful for some one...

Comment: @AshishShukla ok. Will do it.

Comment: @AshishShukla posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not find elegant solution through `AndroidManifest.xml', I've decided to implement part of "choosing" logic through the code. So here what I have:

In the manifest file we define `UrlActivity` that will respond on any url like "http://host.com/abc/...", so it will looks like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.UrlActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" android:pathPrefix="/abc"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then we define interface `Component` (you can choose any name depends on behavior) that is tuned specially for `UrlActivity`. In simple case it can just duplicate analogous methods from activity. For example:

```
public interface Component {
    void onStart();
    void onStop();
}
```

Then in your `UrlActivity` your retrieve uri and choose appropriate Component implementation. For example:

```
private Component component;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();

    if (segments.contains("def")) {
        component = new Component2(...);
    } else {
        component = new Component1(...);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    component.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    component.onStop();
}
```

This solution have advantages compare to @KamranAhmed solution: scalability, reduced duplication. But also it have one flaw: you need to write more code and think about proper architecture for this solution. So it is indeed harder than @KamranAhmed approach, but for me it more DRY and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some thing like this :

```
 <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"     
           android:name=".ui.activities.Activity1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com" 
                  android:pathPattern="http://host.com/abc/12345" 
                  android:pathPrefix="/abc/12345"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  android:name=".ui.activities.Activity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="host.com"  
                  android:pathPattern="http://host.com/abc/def/12345"  
                  android:pathPrefix="/abc/def/12345"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope it Helps you...

Comment: Sorry, this solution will not help, since 12345 is not some concrete id but an abstract implementation of any id (any number)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a better approach, but this works:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.Activity1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="test.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/1.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/2.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/3.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/4.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/5.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/6.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/7.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/8.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/9.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/0.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.Activity2"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="host.com"
            android:pathPattern="/abc/def/.*"
            android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check it.

Comment: Hi, yeah, it will help, but It looks like bit of hack. Anyway, I think there is no better choice for implementing normal pattern in Manifest, so I will accept this answer. Meanwhile I used another solution, but not completely through manifest.

Comment: I would love to know what you used.

Comment: I created one activity that accepts urls like `http://abc/...` and also I've declared an interface `Component` that is tuned for this activity (for example, it could have same methods as activity-lifecycle-methods) and two implementations of it (one for abc/<number>, other for abc/def/<number>). In `Activity.onCreate` I produce instance of Component based on url and then activity work with this component. I'm not saying that it's ideal solution, but there is not such duplications and it is more scalable than "hacking" manifest. But anyway, thank you for your effort and answer. :)